# Problem with IsAuthenticated in ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC

Tags: c#, cookies, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a specific problem using `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`.
If I open a new tab in Chrome and enter my environment eg: `https://localhost:5001`, it opens normally and redirects me to the home page (because I'm already logged in).

However, if I open the site via a link eg: I received an email and it has the link `https://localhost:5001`, if I click on the link I just redirected to the login screen.

But as I'm already logged in the correct would be to redirect to home, if I press f5, the system redirect me to home.

Looking at the debug in the code, in my action, it's stating that `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated = false`

[image]

Now when I press f5 for debug it returns true

[image]

My startup code is like this

```
    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Security/Login";
        options.LogoutPath = "/Security/Logout";
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Security/AccessDenied";
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(15);

        options.Cookie = new CookieBuilder
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            Name = ".CustomName",
            Path = "/",
            SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict,
            SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest,
            Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(15)
        };
    });
```

Comment: Your cookie policy precludes the sending of cookies in the case that are not "same-site". I guess this means that in-links from foreign origins won't work because they won't have the cookie attached. Relaxing `SameSiteMode.Strict` might help, but exposes a larger surface for cross-site-request-forgery mischief.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SameSite cookies explained](https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained/)

> If you set SameSite to Strict, your cookie will only be sent in a
> first-party context. In user terms, the cookie will only be sent if
> the site for the cookie matches the site currently shown in the
> browser's URL bar. When the user is on your site, then the cookie will
> be sent with the request as expected. However when following a link
> into your site, say from another site or via an email from a friend,
> on that initial request the cookie will not be sent.

Use `SameSiteMode.Lax` instead. This will let the browser include an authentication cookie with links from different origin like mail.